# What would happen if we changed Avagadro's Number?

Tags: physical-chemistry

What would happen if we changed Avagardro's number to be smaller, say, $10^6$?

As part of this change, the definition of one mole would change, but the amount of moles in a substance would remain the same. Think as if we are making the number of atoms in an object larger, but keeping the object's volume the same, this making the number of atoms decrease.

**Edit:** to clarify, this question is in regard to if we changed the structure of a theoretical universe so that Avagardro's number was experimentally determined to be exactly one million. I'm asking of what changes would be necessary to make this universe function, and how it would be different from our current universe.

Comment: Related to ohwilleke's answer, why do you believe the number of moles in any given object would remain the same?  As a related question, if you had a rope that was 3m long, and you chose to measure it in feet instead of meters, does the rope shrink to 3ft?

Comment: [We are sort of about to do this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposed_redefinition_of_SI_base_units), but the change will be in the seventh significant figure.

Comment: Changing what definitions we use to calculate things doesn't change the universe at all.  Why should it?  If you're asking what would be implied if a 10^6 gas atoms suddenly took up 22.4 liters at STP, this is an ill-posed question: there are no set of unique ways the universe changes if you suddenly decide one part is dramatically different.

Comment: Your real question seems to be "why does an atom need to be so light to make life work?" Consider DNA. You need one set in every cell. You need exactly the current number of atoms in it, or it can't code as much information. If DNA is a quintillion times heavier, having the necessary set in every cell is a big problem. But you can't arbitrarily make people a quintillion times bigger, because cube-square relationships establish an optimal scale for an organism with a biology like ours. In general, bigger atoms would degrade the complexity of complex biological systems which would be a disaster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the definition of Avogadro's number:

> Avogadro's number is the number of carbon-12 atoms found in 12g of carbon-12.

So let's say this number changes.  This can occur in one of two ways. The first is the exciting but impossible one you are looking at: the mass of carbon-12 atoms changes.  Our current physics assumes the conservation of mass.  If "the class of things we call carbon-12" decreases in mass-per-atom, that mass has to go somewhere.  Where does it go?  The answer to that is 100% dependent on *how* these carbon 12 atoms change mass.  If the mass is "converted" to gamma rays, the result will be very different from if a deity turns a knob on the universe (in which case, I would ask the deity this question).

The more interesting and reasonable answer to this is that our definition of a kilogram changes.  This is interesting because... well... our definition of a kilogram is a bit embarrassing.  As it turns out, we currently define the kilogram with respect to an internationally recognized mass, known as the [International Kilogram Prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilogram) (IKP).  This is literally a block of platinum-iridium alloy that everyone in the world has agreed is "the definition of what 1kg of mass is."  That's it.  That's all a kilogram is.  End of story.

So that suggests that, the mystical and non-existent effect which changed Avogadro's number would change the mass of the IKP at the same time.  If this happened, we would find the two effects cancel each other out, and we'd find that Avogadro's number didn't change at all!  Hilarious!

Interestingly enough, there is an effort to change Avogadro's number.  There's an effort to *set* it to be equal to $6.02214X×10^{23}mol^{-1}$ (where X is one digit that has not yet been agreed upon).  This would be done by setting the definition of the kilogram to be with respect to a certain number of atoms.  This is being done to try to free ourselves from the joy of having our entire unit system built around a single physical block of metal locked in a vault.  If the new definition took place, we could create a kilogram reference out of a polished sphere of silicon like this:
[image: A closeup of a prototype Si sphere]

These spheres are carefully polished to have a very exacting diameter, and thus a very exacting number of atoms within the sphere.  If this change takes place, anyone with sufficient skill could construct a kilogram directly, rather than having to attempt to copy an existing physical kilogram mass!  These spheres are currently undergoing long term stability study to make sure they don't gain or lose mass over time at an unacceptable rate.  Metals pick up an oxide layer over time, and those extra oxygen atoms can add up when you care about parts per million!  If it works, we can replace the IKP, which technically is losing mass slowly because they have to clean it every time it is used, and that cleaning pulls metal off!

Answer (score 0):

[Avagardro's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) is an experimentally determined constant, which is used to convert grams to atoms when the atomic mass number of the atoms in the substance are known. If you changed it, it would no longer convert grams to number of atoms.

The mass of an atom cannot change. It is a fundamental property of the universe. So if you changed Avagardro's number, you would be defining some new unit of mass smaller than a gram by a factor of 6*10^17 in your example, making a mole equal to 1.67 attograms times the atomic mass of the element.

There is no sensible reason for doing this and your question suggests that you are confused about what Avagardro's number means and have some incorrect assumptions about it.

Comment: To clarify, this question is in regard to if we changed the structure of a theoretical universe so that Avagardro's number was experimentally determined to be exactly one million. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @SamWeaver - speculating on non-physical universes really isn't going to be taken too well here. Try Worldbuilding.